# Packer git clone private repository using Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, packer

I want to use ssh keys to git clone private repository im doing a poc

```
source "amazon-ebs" "devbox" {
  ami_name      = var.ami_name
  source_ami    = var.source_ami
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  subnet_id     = var.subnet_id
  ssh_username  = var.ssh_username
  tags = {
    Name = var.ami_name
  }
}

build {
  sources = ["source.amazon-ebs.devbox"]

provisioner "file" {
  source      = "./ssh/"
  destination = "/tmp/"
}

provisioner "shell" {
  inline = [
    "sudo mv /tmp/key-name /home/ubuntu/.ssh/",
    "sudo mv /tmp/key-name.pub /home/ubuntu/.ssh/",
    "sudo mv /tmp/config /home/ubuntu/.ssh/",
    "sudo chmod 600 /home/ubuntu/.ssh/key-name",
    "sudo chmod 644 /home/ubuntu/.ssh/key-name.pub",
    "sudo chmod 644 /home/ubuntu/.ssh/config",
    "sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu/.ssh"
  ]
}
# provisioner "ansible" {
#   playbook_file = "./ansible/playbook.yaml"
#       user          = "${var.ssh_username}"

#       ansible_env_vars = [
#       "ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=debug",
#       "ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False",
#       "ANSIBLE_NOCOLOR=True",
#       ]
#       extra_arguments = [ "--scp-extra-args", "'-O'" ]
# }

  provisioner "shell" {
    script = "./packer-files/bootstrap.sh"
  }
}
```

I'm running these commands to git clone

```
ssh-add -l
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-keygen -f /home/ubuntu/.ssh/key-name -p
ssh-add /home/ubuntu/.ssh/key-name
ssh-add -l
echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
echo "ls"
```

I am getting

> amazon-ebs.devbox: Failed to load key /home/ubuntu/.ssh/key-name: error in libcrypto
>
> ==> amazon-ebs.devbox: Error loading key "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/key-name": error in
> libcrypto

I try these same bash commands when i SSH into same AMI (without these commands) and I can git clone

this is using Ubuntu 22.04

I'm confused

Comment: There are no `git` commands in the Packer config or template. Are you asking about something else?